# For Loop not breaking Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, break

I have been doing the problem in Codeforces, I am able to write the code but the for loop is not breaking. The break under the 'if' condition is not working.

Here is the link :
   https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1167/A

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            String y=sc.next();

            int c=x;

            for(int j=0;j<x;j++){       // This For loop is not breaking
                if(y.charAt(j)==8){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    c--;
                }
            }
            if(c>=11){
                System.out.println("YES" );
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("NO" );
            }
        }
    }
}

Input: 13
       7818005553535
Output(Expected): YES that is c=12
Output: No that is c=0
```

Comment: Your ```if(y.charAt(j)==8)``` is computing an int comparison and not the char comparison you expect. Try changing to ```if(y.charAt(j)=='8')```.

Comment: Isn't it simply possible to answer this problem with `s.length() - s.indexOf("8") >= 11 ? "YES" : "NO"`  ?

Comment: @AxelH no, your solution will not work for those input that are have length of 11 or more but without an '8'. Since ```s.indexOf("8")``` will return -1 and ```s.length() - s.indexOf("8") >= 11``` will result to true

Comment: I noticed that too @Mark, but I am not providing a full proof solution. Note that this is simple enough to solve that issue.

Comment: @AxelH yeah, just add a checking if there is an '8' to your solution then everything will be fine. OP just complicates things. But he will eventually learn from it :)

Comment: Thank you guys it worked, @TreyGraham thankyou .

Answer (score 0):

You're actually checking if char on position `j` is unicode character with code 8, not actually character '8'. And Unicode character witch code 8 is BS (backspace), so you are basically checking if character is backspace.

**you need to check:**

```
if(y.charAt(j) == '8')  // character literal
```

or

```
if(y.charAt(j) == 56)  // integral value of character
```

or

```
if(y.charAt(j) == '\u0038') // character escape sequence (Hex Value)
```

**Unicode Character Codes:**
https://unicode-table.com/pl/#basic-latin